# Dot product with pandas and Na's

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a pandas dataframe with Na's and want to use the `dot` product:

Here is a MWE:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

d = {'col1': [np.nan, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
weight =[1,2]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.dot(weight)
```

The output gives NAs in the first row.

```
0     NaN
1    10.0
dtype: float64
```

What is the way to ignore the Na in the first row of the `df` ?

The expected output should be:

```
0 6 
1 10 
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea is replace missing values by `0` before `dot`:

```
print(df.fillna(0).dot(weight))
0     6.0
1    10.0
dtype: float64
```